# error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

I am just starting to learn PHP and I get this weird error when trying to run my php script:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /-snip-/Account/Register.php on line 9

It is weird because my line 9 is `<h1>Login</h1>` and there is no syntax error. Here is my full script:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("-snip-", "-snip-", "-snip-") or die("Could not connect to the Lunar Servers! Please try again later...");
mysql_select_db("-snip-", $connection) or die("Could not connect to the Lunar DB! Please try again later...");

echo "
    <body style='font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'>    
        <div style='width: 80%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color: #000";
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
";
```

It should connect to my MySQL Database and then display "Login" with a light gray border around it. Sadly, I recieve that error instead and I do not know why.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just look at the syntax highlighting and you'll see the problem

Comment: You close your string at line 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line above it is missing `>` and has a `"` that ends the echo body, so the `<` is unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is here

```
<div style='width: 80%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color: #000";
```

You have incorrect opening-closing quotes for the style tag as well as div tag not closing

```
<div style='width: 80%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color: #000;'>
```

try replacing with something like the above

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line of code:

```
<div style='width: 80%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color: #000";
```

You open it with `'` and close it with `"` - try changing it to this:

```
<div style='width: 80%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color: #000';
```